# ajax for filtering posts by category in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So my question is if anyone can help me out to turn the following into a list of filters that don't require refresh/reload of the page...

I believe the following answer is the closest I can get to a solution: Using ajax on categories and wordpress loops

However, I'm not sure where to implement the code. I'm using the following in my loop.php:

```
<div id="queryMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="business_work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="development_sustainability">Sustainability</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="education">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="health_medecine">Medecine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="human_rights">Human</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="law_order">Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="media_information">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="nations">Nations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="political_economy">Economy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="research_innovation">Research</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="reset">All Posts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now if I want to apply the coding as mentioneenter code hered here - Using ajax on categories and wordpress loops - where should I put the different code snippets and is there a lot of tweaking to be done to it?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#queryMenu ul li a").click(function(){
    var currentCategory = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax-category.php', //sometimes I'm using bloginfo to get current path: url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/ajax.php',
        data: {
            currentCategory: currentCategory
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What and where has to be in ajax-category.php ?